# How can I access django admin when my app is live it give me server error 500?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an app made on django 2.2.5. I was trying to access the django admin so that I can add some data for the app using admin.

When I was accessing the admin on the development server by calling 127.0.0.1:8000/admin everything is going fine and I can add more data to the database using admin page. But I am unable to access my admin page when I am fetching the admin by using(my deployed website ip say(10.2.2.5)/admin.

My admin page is opening but as soon as I am trying to login into it using my id and password it is giving me error(server error 500).

Can someone help me so that I can add data to my website from the admin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run your migrations (i.e. `python manage.py migrate`) in any step while deploying the application?

Comment: Yes,I did several times.

Comment: I would suggest (if your logs are not configured or available) setting `DEBUG = True` for a while and then try to debug the problem with the help of Django traceback. However, it is best to configure logs early on as described by @mawilmsen.

Comment: I have tried with debug=True I am getting an error : Exception Value:  

attempt to write a readonly database.What can I do now @AlfarhanZahedi?

Comment: This means you have to give the required write permission! What database are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite only.

Answer (score -2):

Probably a stupid question... Sorry but have you tried checking the logs? Error 500 means most likely there is an exception and a traceback visible in the application logs.

Which WSGI server do you use to serve the app?

Comment: My app is not in the develoment. It is deployed already. I guess you did not understand my question.

Comment: I am a newbie to django so it will be great if you can help me with this.

Comment: I think I did understand your question. So when it is deployed already, why would you not have any logs? Did you configure logging in your settings.py according to the documentation? Please check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/ and scroll to Examples section. There is an example on how you configure django to log everything into a file.

Comment: @mawilmsen I'd recommend turning your last comment into an answer to this question, along with a basic example of how to use it.

Comment: This would stay as a comment instead of an answer